# Perl end-of-line regex

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I have a Perl script that executes a regex to find a markup tag (`<tag>`).

My regex is: `<tag([^>]+)>`

This works for most intances, however, I've found an instance where it's not working.

If `<tag>` has the following formation....

```
<tag 
attr="12345">
```

The regex works fine.

However, if `<tag>` looks like this.

```
<tag attr="12345"
>
```

No match. I've tested my regex is Notepad++ and it works fine for all instances. The problem is in my Perl script.

I've attempted several end-of-line anchors, but no luck thus far. Any help is much appreciated!

Edited
Here is my line of code.

```
$line =~s/<tag([^>]+)>/<!--tag $1-->/g;
```

Comment: Not sure if the regex is the problem. I've tried:
`$ perl -e 'if (<> . <> =~ /<tag([^>]+)>/) { print "yes\n" }'
<tag attr="12345"
>
yes`
and it works. Maybe you need to show more code (maybe a small repro program).

Comment: Works for me: `my $s = qq(<tag attr="12345"\n>); $s =~ /<tag([^>]+)>/ and print $1;` gives `attr="12345"`.

Comment: Added my line of code.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Sorry, Lester, but I'm not parsing HTML. I'm working with a pipeline with very specific requirements.

Comment: Try this:  `my $line = q/<tag attr="12345\n>/; $line =~ s/<tag([^>]+)>/<!--tag $1-->/g; print "[[$line]]\n";`  You'll see "it works", so the problem must be elsewhere.  Note: You are adding an extra space between "tag" and "attr", and retaining the embedded newline, which may not be what you want, but those are different issues.

Comment: Can you show a short perl script that demonstrates the problem?  I suspect you were running something slightly different than you think you were, because what you present should work fine.

Comment: @AndyLester he's clearly not trying to write a HTML parser, he's looking for specific tag to add a value to. Also, linking to a PHP related page when the question is tagged `perl` is pretty useless.

Comment: My mistake:  Here's the Perl version: http://htmlparsing.com/perl

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $line;` would tell if `$line` has complete or just partial tag.

Comment: If it looks like XML or HTML, try using one of the established modules for that. There are HTML parsers that can be used to parse tags out of text even if they are not HTML tags but looks like them.

Answer (score 0):

You call the string to manipulate `$line`. That's suspicious, because you must have concatenated multiple lines before, to check for multi-line tags.
Please check (or post) you concatenating code too. I'm 90% sure the problem is there.

You have another problem too, which you're not necessarily aware of.
If there are multiple tags on the same line, your regex will replace text between the first and last as well.

```
<tag foo="1">foo bar <tag bar="2">baz spam
```

Will become

```
<!--tag foo="1">foo bar <tag bar="2"-->baz spam
```

after your treatment, although you probably wanted

```
<!-- tag foo="1"-->foo bar <!--tag bar="2"-->baz spam
```

Please use the lazy version of the `+` quantifier: `+?`.

```
$line = ~s/<tag([^>]+?)>/<!--tag $1-->/g;
```